# C++ Error C2100: Illegal Indirection--bubbleSort

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to send a vector into a bubbleSort function to organize numbers from max to min as they are produced one by one, but I am getting the "C2100: Illegal indirection" warning. Can someone please help me out?

```
private: void bubbleSort(vector<int> &matrixPtr)
{
    int temp;             
    int numLength = *matrixPtr.size( );//length of vector 
    for (int i = 1; (i <= numLength);i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
        {
            if (*matrixPtr[j+1] > *matrixPtr[j])      
            { 
                temp = *matrixPtr[j];//Swap elements
                *matrixPtr[j] = *matrixPtr[j+1];
                *matrixPtr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bubbleSort is drawn from another function ahead of it:

```
 bubbleSort(&output);//pass to bubble sort
              for (int rows=0;rows<creation->getZeroRows();rows++)
                {
                 for (int cols=0;cols<creation->getCols();cols++)
                 {
                     txt_DisplayRowSum->Text= String::Concat(txt_DisplayRowSum->Text, (*creation->zeroArrayPtr)[rows][cols]," ");
                 }
                 txt_DisplayRowSum->Text+=" \n";
              }
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Lose the asterisk on `*matrixPtr`; its not a pointer, its a reference. After that, I wish you best of luck in the indexing defect it will no-doubt expose once your code compiles.

Comment: Probably also lose the ampersand on `&output`.

Comment: matrixPtr is a reference to a vector<int>, it contains plain ints, not pointers to them.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly using references.

Instead of `*matrixPtr.size( )` you need `matrixPtr.size()`, and everywhere else in the function you do not need the `*` when referring to `matrixPtr`. Also, when passing the vector to the function, you should pass just `output` and not `&output`.

You should not and can not use references like pointers. While similar, they're different in several important ways. I also recommend [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c) for a good summary of those differences.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried removing the asterisks right after I posted this and it worked. Now I am getting an error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'referring to the bubbleSort(&output). I removed the & but still getting the error. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure? You need to remove the ampersand (&) in the function call, writing `bubbleSort(output)`, but leave the ampersand in your function, that is, `void bubbleSort(vector<int> &matrixPtr)`. That should compile. Your error seems to indicate that you're still trying to pass `&output`.

Comment: Yes, I took out the ampersand to leave bubbleSort(output) and now the error is "error C2440:'type cast': cannot convert from std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::vector<_Ty> "

Comment: Maybe your vector output is declared incorrectly. Is it also a pointer instead of a vector? You should have `std::vector<int> output`, not `std::vector<int>* output`.

Comment: You caught it. I had std::vector<int>* output instead of std::vector<int> output. Thank you very much!